# VitrtualStringTree. How to Drag'n'Drop to ROOT level?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe4, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

A have a tree:
ROOT - VirtualStringTree(You don't see it, TVirtualStringTree.RootNode)

- **My Root Node 1**
- **My Root Node 2**

  - *Second node 1*
  - *Second node 2*
  - *Second node 3*
- **My Root Node 3**

I can Drag'n'Drop "My Root Node 3" to any visible node, but I can't return it to defaut position, to the root level of tree.

I try that:

```
//Part of code from OnDragDrop Event of VirtualStringTree
    if (Sender.DropTargetNode = Sender.RootNode) then
    begin
      for i := 0 to high(Nodes) do
      begin
        LinksTree.MoveTo(Nodes[i], Sender.DropTargetNode, Attachmode, False);
      end;
    end;
```

I places mouse to nowhere, but nothing happens. In DragOver I accepted drop to root if DropTarget is VST.RootNode.

Anybody knows, how to drop node to VST.RootNode if I drag mouse to empty space of component?

Comment: suppose you drop "Root node 3" on "Root node 1" and set `AttachMode` to `amInsertBefore` it will be moved to the root. add `toShowDropmark` in `PaintOptions` to see the drop mark. My logic is as follow: if `Mode` (`TDropMode`) is `dmAbove` I set `AttachMode := amInsertBefore`; `dmOnNode -> amAddChildLast`; `dmBelow -> amInsertAfter`.

Comment: @kobik, drop to an empty space is indicated by the `dmNowhere` drop mode and many examples shows assigning the `amNoWhere` to the attach mode. And this will be the case, I think, because the call of the `MoveTo` looks correct. You can move nodes to the `RootNode` (or `nil`, which means the same), so the only thing I would suspect is a wrong attach mode.

Comment: @TLama, Yes I wanted to mention the `amNoWhere` but you were faster :) In any case I DO NOT implement `amNoWhere` becouse I think It's wrong UI behavior to move nodes when there is no visible target nodes.

Comment: @kobik, I use `amNoWhere` value just to initialize the `AttachMode` local variable. It covers the situation when I forget on a certain drop mode in the `case` statement and that variable has a *"random"* value as it's local. Otherwise I also prevent no target node case by accepting `OnDragOver` event only if there is a target.

Comment: @TLama, I see what you mean. I handle the `case` differently: I simply `Exit` the event in case `Mode==dmNowhere` because I have a bit of   logic before I actually call `MoveTo` which should not be used in case of `dmNowhere`.

Comment: Even is VT source you can see: `amNoWhere, // just for simplified tests, means to ignore the Add/Insert command`. So IMHO `amNoWhere` should be ignored.

Comment: @kobik, to your previous comment... That's fine :) But for this case you must call `MoveTo` if drop mode is `dmNowhere` and you must also accept drag for "nowhere". Drop mode is a *"place where user dropped"* indicator. If it's empty space, you get `dmNowhere`. Determining that the user dropped node(s) inside an empty space on `DropTargetNode==nil` is a wrong way.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't shown your code, but basically, you just need to use a proper (attach) `Mode` parameter for your `MoveTo` method call for situations, when the (drop) `Mode` parameter of your `OnDragDrop` event method equals to `dmNowhere`, which indicates that the user just dropped node(s) to an empty space of the tree. I assume you're having a code like follows to determine the attach mode in your `OnDragDrop` event method:

```
var
  ...
  AttachMode: TVTNodeAttachMode;
begin
  ...
  // the Mode here is a drop mode parameter
  case Mode of
    dmNowhere: AttachMode := amNoWhere; // <- where this stands for no move
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

If that is so, you can just tell the tree to attach the node e.g. as a last child by changing the attach mode to `amAddChildLast` if the drop mode will be `dmNowhere`:

```
var
  ...
  AttachMode: TVTNodeAttachMode;
begin
  ...
  // the Mode here is a drop mode parameter
  case Mode of
    dmNowhere: AttachMode := amAddChildLast; // <- attach node as a last child
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dmOnNode` be mapped to `amAddChildLast` also?

Comment: @kobik, that's not important here. The main point is that `dmNowhere` which indicates drop to an empty space. I think that OP assigned `amNoWhere` to the attach mode, which did no move.

Comment: I guess you are right but still I prefer your previous answer where you show all attach modes. +1